# How can I write a query as a value in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables on MySQL (using phpMyAdmin), looking like the following:
Table 1:

```
Country    Total Minutes
USA        100
USA        90
Canada     60
Mexico     80
UK         90
France     70
France     10
Germany    10
```

In Table 2, what I need to do is the following:

```
Region           Total Minutes
North America    USA+USA+Canada+Mexico Mins
Europe           UK+France+France+Germany Mins
```

Is there a way to have a row be the result of a query?

Comment: Do you have a region column in table 1?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Better make a table that connects your regions to your Countrys, and if you want to total minutes per region, just query that when you need it.

Comment: @Pablo, USA, Canada, Mexico are in North America, so I would like to take the sum of their values in Table 1 and output it in the row Total Minutes in Table 2. For instance North America would be 100+90+60+80 minutes.

Comment: @Nanne that sounds like a good idea, could you further explain how to do this?

Comment: @Jack, no Table 1 does not contain that information.

Comment: @jesterll it's basically jack's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need a region column in table 1:

```
SELECT region, SUM(`Total Minutes`)
FROM timespent
GROUP BY region;
```

Or a separate `region <-> country` table:

```
SELECT region, SUM(`Total Minutes`)
FROM myregions r
INNER JOIN timespent t USING (country)
GROUP BY r.region;
```

The regions table would look like this:

```
region        | country
--------------+--------
North America | USA
North America | Mexico
```

If you can't change anything in your database, look at Andomar's solution :)

Comment: If you can change the database this is definitely the better option, +1

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You could translate the countries to regions in a subquery.  The outer query can then `group by` on region:

```
select  Region
,       sum(TotalMinutes) as TotalMinutes
from    (
        select  case country
                when 'USA' then 'North America'
                when 'France' then 'Europe'
                end as Region
        ,       TotalMinutes
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Region
```

Comment: He could do that, but it would be better to store that information in a table rather than in a query.

Comment: @Pablo but this is probably the only other solution if he can't change his database :) +1